# What is the comic-canon name(s) of Lex Luthor's father?

Tags: dc, superman, lex-luthor

Growing up on Smallville, I had always assumed Lex Luthor's father had a canon name of Lionel. Recently, Supergirl also featured a Lionel Luthor, which helped to further this belief. Then the linked question happened. Then I started looking at

With addition of a little more research bringing up older names for him, including Jules Thorul, or Alexander Luthor, I'm questioning if "Lionel" was his actual comic-canon name, or if it was just cemented due to Smallville and later adopted in comics.

Inspired by: [What is the origin of the name Lexcorp?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124150/what-is-the-origin-of-the-name-lexcorp)

Comment: By canon, you mean "in the comics"? Presumably the original incarnation (before any universe splits and reboots)? Because these are all "canon" - just different canons.

Comment: @phantom42 Yeeeeup, updated to address that.

Comment: Mr. Luthor.  He dropped out of medical school.

Comment: It *must* begin with an L. I'd bet good money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lionel was the name used in the miniseries Secret Identity, and is currently the most often used name for Lex's father.  As is true of much of Superman's history coming from other media, the name is most likely used due to its use in Smallville.

There have been many period in comics history where he's gone under other names, as well as un-named. Details of the family history undergoing many changes. The idea that Lex killed one of both of his parents (often for insurance money) has cropped up in a number of those versions.

In the silver age, the name "Thorul" was a name taken by Lena, taken in an attempt to distance herself and hide from her family, particularly her brother.

[Wiki page](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Lionel_Luthor_(New_Earth))